# why does the dictionary key not update to record the change in keys

Tags: python, dictionary

the goal is to increase the dictionary key by 1 so all values generated by for loop are stored in a dictionary

code

```
counting = {}
numbers = 1


for i in range(1, 11):
    counting[numbers] = (i)
    numbers + 1

print(counting)
```

but in the final result the dictionary only has one key and one stored value that is

result of running the code
{1: 10}

how do i make it that the keys changes with each loop and stores all the values generated

but in the final result the dictionary only has one key and one stored value that is

result of running the code
{1: 10}

how do i make it that the keys changes with each loop and stores all the values generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `numbers += 1` or `numbers = numbers + 1` instead of `numbers + 1` if you want to update the variable.

When python sees `numbers + 1`, it just evaluates that line, gets 2, and does nothing with that value. If you don't have an = sign, the variable will not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you realize, but there's a silly typo in your code. After assigning the value to dictionary, you increasing the count of `numbers`, but not assigning it. So, just use `+=` assignment operator.

```py
counting = {}
numbers = 1


for i in range(1, 11):
    counting[numbers] = (i)
    numbers += 1

print(counting)
```

O/P:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10}
```